# matlab will two different cameras give me different results?

Tags: matlab, camera, area

the next code gets an image of a grape that I photograph (is called: 'full_img') and calculate the area of the grape:

```
RGB = imread(full_img);
GRAY = rgb2gray(RGB);

threshold = graythresh(GRAY);
originalImage = im2bw(GRAY, threshold);

originalImage = bwareaopen(originalImage,250);
SE = strel('disk',10);
IM2 = imclose(originalImage,SE);
originalImage = IM2;

labeledImage = bwlabel(originalImage, 8);     % Label each blob so we can make measurements of it

blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, originalImage, 'all');   
numberOfBlobs = length(blobMeasurements);

pixperinch=get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch');   %# find resolution of your display
dpix=blobMeasurements(numberOfBlobs).Area; %# calculate distance in pixels 
dinch=dpix/pixperinch;                     %# convert to inches from pixels
dcm=dinch*2.54;                            %# convert to cm from inches
blobArea = dcm;                            % Get area.
```

If I photograph the same grape with the same conditions by different cameras (photographed it from the same distance and the same lightning), will I get the same results? (what if I have a camera of 5 Mega Pixel and 12 Mega Pixel?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. You go from image coordinates to world coordinates using dpix/pixperinch. In general this is wrong. It will only work for a specific image (and that alone), if you know the pixperinch. In order to get the geometric characteristics of an object in an image (eg length, area etc), you must back-project the image pixels in the Cartesian space using the Camera matrix and the inverse projective transformation, in order to get Cartesian coordinates (let along calibrating the camera for lens distortion, which is a nonlinear problem). Then, you can perform the calculations. You code won't work even for the same camera.
See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) for more.

Comment: thank you. as the camera is better, should I get better result? or not surely?

Comment: I'm getting almost the same results for a specific image by 1 camera. my question is: if I buy a newer and better camera, will I get better results than the first camera..?

Comment: Alon, I looked at your code more closely. I see that you use ScreenPixelsPerInch to get the pixels per inch. This returns the pixels per inch **on your monitor**! In other words, the DPI. It is not related to the geometric length of the blob. If you change your resolution, this will change. Your code is not correct in finding the physical area of the blob.

Comment: thank you and sorry, I forgot to write something:
I added a circle to the image (right near the grape). I know the circle area (named: real_circle_area.) After that, I photograph and calculate the grape area (named: grape_area) and the circle area (through the code above, named: circle_area). next I'm doing: repair_area = circle_area / real_circle_area. then I repair the area of the grape: new_grape_area = grape_area / repair_area.

now, will I get the same results (less or more) in two different cameras? thank you very much!

Comment: Again, no. This is not the way to calculate physical dimensions from an image. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix more carefully.